# Let X be a random variable with the 3-parameter Weibull pdf and cdf

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let X be a random variable with the [3-parameter Weibull pdf and cdf](http://reliawiki.org/images/math/b/7/c/b7c906a5ccc58703482a21ca13f8f140.png) (replace $\gamma$  with  ν and replace $\eta$ with $\alpha$)

a) Find the quantile function. For α = 1, ν = 0, and β = 4, find the 0.95 quantile
(use a calculator to arrive at a numerical answer and round to two decimal places).

Solved! $F^{-1}(q) = \alpha (-ln(1-q))^{1/\beta}+ν$

For q = .95, α = 1, ν = 0, and β = 4: $F^{-1}(q) = 1.32$

b) Suppose α = 1, ν = 0, and β > 0. Find $E[X^2]$

Solved!
$f(x)=β(x)^{β−1}e^{−x^{β}}$ when i plug in α=1, ν=0, β>0 so $E[X^2]= \int_0^\infty x^2β(x)^{β−1}e^{−x^{β}}$

U SUBSTITUTION: $u = x^\beta$ and $du = \beta x^{\beta-1}$ and $u^{2/\beta} = x^2$ which will give you $\int_0^\infty u^{2/\beta}e^{-u} = \int_0^\infty u^{((2/\beta) + 1) - 1}e^{-u} = \Gamma((2/\beta)+1) = (2/\beta)\Gamma(2/\beta)$

Quantiles were really rushed over in class and not really well explained so I'm having trouble figuring this question out. Will edit in my progress as i go on.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a density function $f(t) = 4t^{3}e^{-t^4}$

The quantile fuction is a function $Q(p)$ (where $p$ is a probability so $0<p<1$) defined by:

$$Q(p) = \inf\left\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} : p \leq F(x)\right\rbrace$$ or in words, the first time the value of the CDF reaches the probability $p$. So your goal is to compute the CDF from the PDF you have above (you'll get a function $G(t)$), and then solve the equation $G(t) = p$. See if you can continue from there.

Comment: I did part a the way we did in class so I'm pretty sure that part a is right at least. I'm now working on b and would be glad to get input on that! Thanks!

Comment: You have a pdf. How do you usually calculate second moments from the pdf?

Comment: right now what i have is $f(x) = \beta(x)^{\beta-1}e^{-x^{\beta}}$ when i plug in $\alpha = 1, ν = 0, \beta > 0$ so $E[X^2] = \int_0^\infty x^2\beta(x)^{\beta-1}e^{-x^{\beta}}$ but I'm not sure how to integrate that

Comment: Got it! Used u substitution